# Getting current location with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to collect my exact location with python and all the result that I am getting is the location of my Internet service provide. I am just wondering if it is possible to avoid such event from happening.

Best regards,
Helicon

Update:
the following code is what I use.

```
import requests
import json

send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'

r = requests.get(send_url)

j = json.loads(r.text)

lat = j['latitude']

lon = j['longitude']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the website [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/):

```
In [10]: import json, requests

In [11]: info = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').json()

In [12]: info['city']
Out[12]: 'Bryan'

In [13]: info['region']
Out[13]: 'Texas'
```

It will also give latitude and longitude. Just use `info['loc']`